# Applying for postdoctoral fellowships: priorities?

Tags: funding, postdocs, university

I am going to graduate with a PhD in applied math/CS in early fall (I am studying in Europe). Due to various factors, there are not too many places that would fit my previous research well enough for me not to basically have to switch fields or at least work in a research group that knows nothing about what I do. I want to mainly choose a host based on their research interests (which should mostly align with mine) and the contributions I could expect to make in a collaboration. With this in mind, there are two hosts in the US, two in Israel, and two in Japan who I am considering and where I have reasonable chances to get in either via fellowship or directly with the PI. However, there are obviously more factors I should consider, but I have too little experience to order my priorities. For example, how important is prestige of the university? The hosts in Japan are in two of the smaller and less famous universities, even though they're well respected in my field and I'd have an advantage as I know Japanese, and have many acquaintances in the area. I also like that Japan is safe and don't mind the long hours. Meanwhile, the hosts in the US are at highly prestigious universities (both Ivy League) - but try as I might, I have little enthusiasm for both places, considering I've visited there before (not the hosts though) and didn't feel comfortable.  The two PIs in Israel are the ones I know the least about (their research is slightly less close to my current one), though they seem to be quite big shots. I've just heard mixed reviews of life in Israel regarding safety etc, plus my Hebrew is pretty bad and would need a serious upgrade if I want to communicate more.

My question is now how to weigh things like personal preference for a location against prestige/networking in the geographical area. If I do stick with academia, I definitely want to give myself the best chance possible, and naturally expect to have to make sacrifices for it, but considering my not-so-great PhD experience, I want to do a postdoc somewhere that appeals to me beyond prestige.

Comment: Given the state of the job market in many fields you should just apply for all of them, since it's nowhere near guaranteed you'll get any offers (this may not be true for some areas of CS at the moment).

Comment: Yeah, that's the plan anyway. My advisor is just discouraging me from attempting to go to Japan, which has been making me somewhat insecure about the whole thing (it's the most likely to succeed too from what people are telling me).

Comment: This is a highly personal question. Judging from your post you already have a pretty good understanding of the non-personal factors, but how to weigh them against personal ones such as crime or local culture is I for us to do. That's necessarily your call!

Answer (score 1):

The main reasons I can think of to do a postdoc are

1. Continuing your research work, expanding your academic portfolio
2. Getting good reference letters from leaders in your field.
3. Expand your domain knowledge - if you are interested in a new field, a postdoc with a relevant host is an excellent way of familiarizing yourself with it.
4. Practice your academic faculty skills: mentoring students, writing grants etc.

I have listed these in the order of their importance (in my mind), but yours may be different.

With these considerations in mind, ask yourself which position would best facilitate these goals and what you'd need to do in order to achieve them.

From my experience, language barriers are not a major issue in Israel: most adult Israelis (especially those in the age range of 18-40, and definitely all in academia) can speak English fairly well.